# Hdmi sound output

Tags: sound, hdmi

Hello I just built my first computer and it works fantastic all except for no sound from my hdmi output. I was wondering if this is perhaps a driver issue or when I built the computer I chose HD audio rather than AC 97. Hopefully it is an easy enough solution.

Thanks

Comment: `alsamixer`? Also [Pulseaudio Sound Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol/). Also, what sound card are you using?

Comment: This may also be a graphics card driver issue. Which card/driver did you install?

Comment: You can find both using `lspci -v` in terminal - which should list hardware and drivers.

Answer (score 0):

If the drivers and hardware are setup correctly, you may just need to configure the settings to route the sound through HDMI. For this, I use [Pulseaudio Volume Control](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol/).

Once installed, search for Pulseaudio Volume Control or just run `pavucontrol` in terminal.
Then look for this:
[image: Sound Settings - Config]