# No sound through HDMI after trying other options

Tags: sound, hdmi

Hi all recently installed ubuntu   64 bit...  Total noob to ubuntu so if anyone can help me in really simple terms how to play sound through my television using the hdmi cable it would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If the drivers and hardware are setup correctly, you may just need to configure the settings to route the sound through HDMI. For this, I use [Pulseaudio Volume Control](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol/).

Once installed, search for Pulseaudio Volume Control, or just run `pavucontrol` in terminal.
Then look for this:
[image: Sound Settings - Config]

---

<sub>Yes, this is a duplicate of my previous answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/383973/178596)</sub>